# How to unit test a Angular Filter that uses a function from a Service?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing

I am using Jasmine to unit test my Angular project.
I succesfully unit tested a filter without any dependencies. 
But how would i test a filter/controller/service that uses functions from other services?

```
movieApp.filter('usernameFilter', ['registerService',function(registerService){
    return function(input){
        input = input || '';

        if(input.length <= 5){
            return 'This username is not long enough';
        }
        else if(registerService.uniqueUsername(input)){
            return 'This username is already being used';
        }

    };
}]);
```

I have the following filter that uses the uniqueUsername function from the registerService. This function basically compares the input of the user with the existing usernames in the local storage.

What could be an easy way of testing this filter?

```
describe('The username filter', function(){
    var $filter, registerService;

    beforeEach(function(){
        module('movieApp');

        inject(function(_$filter_, _registerService_){
            $filter = _$filter_;
            registerService = _registerService_;
        });
    });

    it('Should give an output when the username is already being used', function(){

        spyOn(registerService, 'uniqueUsername').and.callFake(function(){
            return true;
        });


        var input = 'username';

        result = $filter('usernameFilter')(input);

        expect(registerService.uniqueUsername).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(result).toBe('This username is already being used');
    });
});
```

I get the error    Expected spy uniqueEmail to have been called.
            at Object. (spec/test.js:54:45)
        Expected undefined to be 'This username is already being used'.
            at Object. (spec/test.js:55:24)

This is my service:

```
movieApp.service('registerService',['databaseService', function(databaseService){
    this.uniqueEmail = function(email){
        var exists = false;

        users = databaseService.get("users");

        if(users != null){

            users.forEach(function(e, i){
                if(e.mail == email){
                    exists = true;
                }
            })
            return exists;
        };
    }

}]);
```

Comment: You obviously shouldn't mess with local storage in tests. Just mock registerService service and make registerService.uniqueUsername return true or false in different specs to test all possible cases.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, i used mock on the service but still getting an error.

Comment: I would suggest to mock it totally, this allows to test current unit (filter) in isolation. However, I don't see from the code above how uniqueUsername can be not called. Please, recreate this error as a fiddle/plunk, this may help.